# Uitableview number of row in section

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, uitableview

i've data like this:

```
(
      {
    code = 000932;
    date = "2013-11-29 18:17:03";
},
    {
    code = 000933;
    date = "2013-11-29 18:17:03";
},
    {
    code = 000934;
    date = "2013-11-29 18:17:03";
},
    {
    code = 000935;
    date = "2013-11-29 18:17:03";
},
    {
    code = 000936;
    date = "2013-11-29 18:17:03";
},
    {
    code = 000937;
    date = "2013-11-29 18:17:03";
},
    {
    code = 000938;
    date = "2013-11-29 18:17:03";
},
    {
    code = 000939;
    date = "2013-11-29 18:17:03";
},
    {
    code = 000940;
    date = "2013-11-29 18:17:03";
},
    {
    code = 001004;
    date = "2013-12-24 01:27:34";
},
    {
    code = 001005;
    date = "2013-12-24 01:27:34";
},
    {
    code = 001006;
    date = "2013-12-24 01:27:35";
},
    {
    code = 001007;
    date = "2013-12-24 01:33:17";
},
    {
    code = 001008;
    date = "2013-12-24 01:33:17";
},
    {
    code = 001009;
    date = "2013-12-24 01:33:17";
}
 )
```

then i sort it and 're-group' it into `NSMutableDictionary`:

```
-(void)fetchCoupon{
    NSLog(@"3");
    userCoupon *object;
    //[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/transaction/coupon/list",serverUrl];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                                 @"token":[bbox_helper getToken],
                                 };
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:url parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        BOOL found;
        NSLog(@"data->%@",[responseObject objectForKey:@"data"]);
        for(NSDictionary *news_objects in [responseObject objectForKey:@"data"]){
            userCoupon *object=[[userCoupon alloc] initWithDictionary:news_objects];

            if(![coupon containsObject:object]){
                [coupon addObject:object];
            }
        }


        for (object in coupon)
        {
            NSString *c = object.date;


            found = NO;

            for (NSString *str in [coupon_section allKeys])
            {
                if ([str isEqualToString:c])
                {
                    found = YES;
                }
            }
            if (!found)
            {
                [coupon_section setValue:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:c];
            }

        }

        // Loop again and sort the books into their respective keys
        for (object in coupon)
        {

            [[coupon_section objectForKey:object.date] addObject:object];

        }


        NSLog(@"data---%@",[[coupon_section allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
            return [a compare:b options:NSNumericSearch];
        }]);

        NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)[[[coupon_section allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
            return [a compare:b options:NSNumericSearch];
        }]count]);
        progressView.mode = MRProgressOverlayViewModeCheckmark;

        progressView.titleLabelText = @"Done";

        [table_transaction reloadData];

        [table_gift reloadData];

        [table_coupon reloadData];

        [beetlebox performBlock:^{

            [progressView dismiss:YES];

        } afterDelay:2.0];


    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        progressView.mode = MRProgressOverlayViewModeCross;

        progressView.titleLabelText = @"Failed communicating with server";


    }];

}
```

then in tableviewsection i create like this

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
        return [[[[[coupon_section allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
            return [a compare:b options:NSNumericSearch];
        }] reverseObjectEnumerator]allObjects] count];
    }

}
```

and then in section titleheader

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)sections
{

        return [[[[[coupon_section allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
            return [a compare:b options:NSNumericSearch];
        }] reverseObjectEnumerator]allObjects]objectAtIndex:sections];;

    }

}
```

and then number of row:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)sections {

        return  [[[coupon_section allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
            return [a compare:b options:NSNumericSearch];
        }]count];

}
```

/////////////////////cell show

```
    userCoupon *obj = [coupon objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    static NSString* cells=@"getGift";
    pointCell *cell = [[pointCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cells];

    if(!cell){
        cell = [[pointCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cells];
    }
    NSLog(@"data->%@",obj.code);
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.merchant_name.text = obj.code;
    cell.status.hidden = YES;
    cell.icon_status.hidden = YES;
    return cell;
```

the result is: https://i.cloudup.com/V3wW9w4glP.png

i want it grouped by date (already done) and then get right of data on section with right value. can anyone help me with this??

Comment: Show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `willDisplayCell`

Comment: hi @ValentinShamardin already added

Comment: How do you fork code for each section? You always use `indexPath.row` and do not use `indexPath.section`. As result, text in each section is the same.

Comment: @ValentinShamardin what do you mean?

Comment: can you be more specific. what exactly do you want to display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not still clear from question where is the problem you are facing.
However if you want to display data in cell you can apply following approach.

**Data Recieved:**

```
(
  {
code = 000932;
date = "2013-11-29 18:17:03";    

},
   {
code = 000933;
date = "2013-11-29 18:17:03";
}
)
```

If you have **sorted array named coupon** then you can set elements in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** as follows:

```
cell.name.text = [[coupon objectAtIndex:indexpath.row]objectForKey:@"code"];
```

OR

```
cell.name.text =[[coupon objectAtIndex:indexpath.row]objectForKey:@"date"];
```

Comment: @YAZID - If this not what you want to achieve - Please add code for declaration all array,dictionary you have used.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
NSArray *couponsArray = [[[coupon_section allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
        return [a compare:b options:NSNumericSearch];
    }] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
userCoupon *obj = [couponsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 0):

The [JSON sample project](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/JSON/JSON/JSONTableViewController.m) in [TLIndexPathTools](http://tlindexpathtools.com) does almost exactly what you're asking for.

In particular, the `TLIndexPathDataModel` class organizes the data into sections for you and greatly simplifies data source and delegate methods with APIs like `[dataModel numberOfRowsInSection:]` and `[dataModel itemAtIndexPath:]`.